# Could AI be used to generate questions from a database input?

Tags: machine-learning, gaming, natural-language-processing

I confront to the next scenario:

> Let's say I have stored data about football matches between different teams: lineups, scorers, yellow cards, and many other events.
>
> I need to generate everyday some questions about the matches that will be played on that day. So, if I give an input of two teams, I would like a related question to be generated, based on previous data of matches between those two teams.
>
> For example, if my input are *"TeamA"* and *"TeamB"*, I would expect a question of the type:
>
> - *"Will there be less than 2 goals scored in the match?"*"
> - "*Will PlayerX score a goal during the match?"*
>
> Of course I expect these questions to make sense based on previous data from matches between the two given teams.

So, my questions are:

- Would be a good solution to use AI to generate these questions? It would make sense?
- What would be the best approach?

Answer (score 3):

One simple approach to consider would be storing each statement as a template made in advance.

- Will there be `less/more` than `x` goals scored in the match?
- Will `player` score a goal during the match?
- ...

The system will pick a random statement and will fill the variable fields with some statistically generated data between `teamA` and `teamB`; here you have your question.

---

**Example**: *Will there be `less/more` than `x` goals scored in the match?*

- `less/more` fragment may be random
- `x` may be the mean of the goals scored considering all the matches between `teamA` and `teamB`

---

**Example**: *Will `player` score a goal during the match?*

- `player` may be a random choice between the top-goalscorer of `teamA` or `teamB`

Comment: It seems like a good idea, I think I'll give it a try, but for the moment I'll wait for more possible solutions before mark your answer as the good one. Thanks!

Comment: Your welcome. Personally I tend to avoid AI if it is not strictly necessary. If I'm not mistaken, using an AI based approach would mean retraining your model daily with the data of the new matches; that's probably an overkill. We'll see, I'm curious about clever AI solutions.

Comment: You can use historical data like average no. of goals in the season, player statistics, etc to generate questions that would seem more real! For example, if a team has scored on average 3 goals in the season till now, the question could be "Will there be more than 3 goals scored in the match?" Or suppose if a player A scored no goals as a striker, "Will A score a goal today?"